# Inheriting from a C++ class with no virtual functions

Tags: c++, dependencies

We have a log implementation that's based on std::ostream with a custom stream buffer. We implement our application's instance of the log class via a Schwarz counter.

To avoid coupling our lower level classes to our log implementation, we can pass a reference to a std::ostream. In this way our lower level classes can log to std::cout, std::cerr or to the instance created via the Schwarz counter.

I have one problem with this. The log implementation sets its severity via an overload of the stream operator:

```
// Overload the << operator to set the log message severity
inline CLogStream& operator << (CLogStream& myLogStream, eMsgType::type msgTypeCurrent)
{
  myLogStream.SetMsgTypeCurrent(msgTypeCurrent);
  return ( myLogStream ) ;
}
```

This allows us to use the logger like this:

```
CLog::Main << CLog::MSG_FATAL << "Fatal error" << std::endl;
```

I'd like to create a reference to our app's instance of the log which is locked to a particular severity. That way, I can pass our utility classes two std::ostream references. One of these would be used for normal reporting and the other for error reporting. These could be set to std::cout and std::cerr, or to some kind of object referring to our log object instance.

Unfortunately the std::ostream operator << aren't virtual as far as I'm aware, so I'm not sure how to design such an object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If `SetMsgTypeCurrent` is not `virtual` (i.e. `CLogStream` is not designed for inheritance) then tough.

Comment: @Jon: I can change the definition of SetMsgTypeCurrent, so can make it virtual if that would help. But I need to access the class via std::ostream, so I don't see what options that would give me. The only virtual functions I'm aware of are down in std::streambuf, and none of them seem useful for this purpose.

Comment: Not an answer, but: I can see other problems with this design as well. In particular, it's not thread-safe: Another thread could interfere between the `<< CLog::MSG_FATAL` and the `<< "Fatal error"`. Is changing the design completely an option?

Comment: @jogojapan: when the class was designed, threads were excluded from the app design. It's been suggested that we relax this constraint, so a design change is almost certainly in the pipeline. Another problem with this design is that the log messages are generated even if the log level is such that they don't get output. I think we can solve both of these problems together via some kind of wrapper, but that's a few months and a design review away.

Answer (score 1):

`iostream` has virtual member functions (specifically, `~ios_base`) so you can perform a `dynamic_cast` in the `operator<<`:

```
inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, eMsgType::type msgTypeCurrent) {
  if (CLogStream *myLogStream = dynamic_cast<CLogStream *>(&os)) {
    myLogStream->SetMsgTypeCurrent(msgTypeCurrent);
  } else {
    os << "TYPE: " << static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<eMsgType::type>
      ::type>(msgTypeCurrent) << ": ";
  }
  return os;
}
```

Comment: @PeterWood `dynamic_cast` will have some overhead, but for logging it's likely to be dominated by IO.  Instrumenting the code will reveal whether this is the case.

Comment: Wouldn't this operator have to be exposed to our low level class along with at least some parts of the log class? I'd like to remove all knowledge of the log class from the low level classes.

Comment: @SimonElliott then don't inline it. just declare it in the header and implement it in-lib. I assume they have knowledge of at least the message type parameter or this is all somewhat pointless. (and +1, ecatmur, nice answer).

Comment: @SimonElliott you could make the operator non-inline.  Alternatively instead of `dynamic_cast` to `CLogStream *` you could `dynamic_cast` to an interface defined alongside `eMsgType`.

Answer (score 1):

If the setting of the severity is persistent, such that both tese lines result in a log entry with fatal severity

```
CLog::Main << CLog::MSG_FATAL << "Log entry 1: " << some_data << std::endl;
CLog::Main << "Log entry 2: " << some_other_data << std::endl;
```

then your logging class is already correctly designed to be passed along as a generic `ostream&`. You just need separate logger instances for the different log-levels that are supported by the utility classes.

This is written under the assumption that the logger class has been inherited from `ostream` to take advantage of the existing `operator<<` overloads.
In that case, the `operator<<` for `some_data` and `some_other_data` are already completely unaware that the output goes to a log stream.

Comment: That would work, but I was hoping to use the same instance everywhere. Users can add various output interface options to the log instance (file, UDP, stdout etc) - these wouldn't be present in the new instances unless we added a "clone" method of some sort.

Comment: @SimonElliott: The problem with a single instance is that that instance can't determine at which level the next output should occur. On the other hand, it should be possible for the users to apply different options to the different instances.

Comment: maybe they can all share the stream buffer: that's where most of the real work happens.

Comment: @SimonElliott: It is possible, but not advisable. The consequences of sharing a stream buffer between multiple streams are 1) lifetime management of the buffer becomes increasingly harder, 2) if data gets written to multiple streams simultaneously, the output will be intermixed (resulting in an unreadable log), 3) you force those streams to write to the same destination.

Answer (score 1):

Read about `ios_base::iword()`. It gives you access to an array of `long` values in the stream object that you can use to store things like flags and special values.